# TriangleTest using Junit: void type is not allowed

Tags: java, junit, compiler-errors, void

I have this code and I tried to create unit tests using Junit. When I try to test the MAIN as following;

```
@Test
public void testMain(){
    assertEquals(determineType(0,1,1),"ABCDEF");
}
```

It keeps telling me that void type is not allowed here. What I have to do?

---

```
package triangle;

public class Triangle {


    public static void determineType(int a, int b, int c) {
        if (a >= (b + c) || c >= (b + a) || b >= (a + c)) {
            System.out.println("Not a Triangle");
        } else if (a == b && b == c) {
            System.out.println("Equilateral Triangle");
        } else if (((a * a) + (b * b)) == (c * c) || ((a * a) + (c * c)) == (b * b) || ((c * c) + (b * b)) == (a * a)) {
            System.out.println("Right Triangle");
        } else if (a != b && b != c && c != a) {
            System.out.println("Scalene Triangle");
        } else if ((a == b && b != c) || (a != b && c == a) || (c == b && c != a)) {
            System.out.println("Isosceles Triangle");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        determineType(1, 1, 9);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I don't know your level of Java programming knowledge, but the error is correct since you're trying to check if a String and void types are equal which is impossible to check in the first place. Your `determineType` method does not return anything, therefore it cannot be asserted that way. What you should do is to return a value in each case and then assert it against a value.

Comment: assertEquals needs two parameters: **the expected value**, and the ** actual value ** .<br/>

but determineType is ovid, so has just no value to return , So you get the error in assertEquals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, I have fixed the errors

TestCode

```
    @Test
    public void testMain(){
        assertEquals(determineType(0,1,1),"Not a Triangle");
    }
```

SourceCode

```
package triangle;

public class Triangle {


    public static String determineType(int a, int b, int c) {

        if (a >= (b + c) || c >= (b + a) || b >= (a + c)) {
            return "Not a Triangle";
        } else if (a == b && b == c) {
            return "Equilateral Triangle";
        } else if (((a * a) + (b * b)) == (c * c) || ((a * a) + (c * c)) == (b * b) || ((c * c) + (b * b)) == (a * a)) {
            return "Right Triangle";
        } else if (a != b && b != c && c != a) {
            return "Scalene Triangle";
        } else if ((a == b && b != c) || (a != b && c == a) || (c == b && c != a)) {
            return "Isosceles Triangle";
        }
        // other case
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(determineType(1, 1, 9));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to test methods that don't return anything (void), but you must test that method's side effects, but here in your case `determineType` method not showing any side-effects, it is more like a check method and not returning anything i.e. `void`, and since it not returning anything so you can't use `assertEquals(expected,actual)`, because `assertEquals` is always a comparison between something *actual result of your operation vs expected result*.

Therefore in order to test this method, you could change the return type of `determineType` method from `void` to `String`( i.e. remove `sysouts` and just `return` the result of your each comparison condition r\e.g. "Not a Triangle" etc.).

Then `5` different test cases to check each condition specified in your `determineType`method, and compare the returned `String` with your expected output.

Something like,

```
    @Test
    public void testNotATriangle(){
        assertEquals(determineType(0,1,1), "Not a Triangle");
    }

    @Test
    public void testEquilateralTriangle(){
        assertEquals(determineType(1,1,1), "Equilateral Triangle");
    }

    // other test case here, for each condition

   public static String determineType(int a, int b, int c) {

        if(a >= (b+c) || c >= (b+a) || b >= (a+c) ) {
            return "Not a Triangle";
        } else if(a==b && b==c) {
            return "Equilateral Triangle";
        } else if (((a * a) + (b * b)) == (c * c) || ((a * a) + (c * c)) == (b * b)|| ((c * c)      + (b * b)) == (a * a)) {
            return "Right Triangle";
        } else if(a!=b && b!=c && c!=a) {
            return "Scalene Triangle";
        } else if ((a==b && b!=c ) || (a!=b && c==a) || (c==b && c!=a)) {
            return "Isosceles Triangle";
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        determineType(1,1,9);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would change the method a little bit, and instead of printing out,  I would return an enum denoting the Triangle type. It will be much easier to test and actually use that method in other places.

```java
public class Triangle {

    public static TriangleType determineType(int a, int b, int c) {
        if (a >= (b + c) || c >= (b + a) || b >= (a + c)) {
            return TriangleType.NONE;
        } else if (a == b && b == c) {
            return TriangleType.EQUILATERAL;
        } else if (((a * a) + (b * b)) == (c * c) || ((a * a) + (c * c)) == (b * b) || ((c * c) + (b * b)) == (a * a)) {
            return TriangleType.RIGHT;
        } else if (a != b && b != c && c != a) {
            return TriangleType.SCALENE;
        } else if ((a == b && b != c) || (a != b && c == a) || (c == b && c != a)) {
            return TriangleType.ISOSCELES;
        }
        return TriangleType.NONE;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final TriangleType type = determineType(1, 1, 9);
        System.out.println(type);
    }

    enum TriangleType {
        EQUILATERAL, RIGHT, SCALENE, ISOSCELES, NONE
    }
}
```

And the test will be as follows:

```java
@Test
public void determineType() {
    Assertions.assertAll(
            () -> assertEquals("Should be isosceles", Triangle.TriangleType.ISOSCELES, Triangle.determineType(2, 2, 3)),
            () -> assertEquals("Should be equilateral", Triangle.TriangleType.EQUILATERAL, Triangle.determineType(2, 2, 2)),
            () -> assertEquals("Should be right", Triangle.TriangleType.RIGHT, Triangle.determineType(4, 3, 5))
    );
}
```